# facebook sdk session doesn't open on emulator or other devices except one

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

Ok so I'm trying to fiddle with the FB sdk lately and it's giving me some hard times.
I've ran the code on my own device and it downloads the profile picture and name as it should but now I want to test it on an emulator and that same code doesn't work. Why would there be any difference?

P.s facebook app is intalled on the emulator and it has access to the web so I cant see what could be wrong? this is running from the same machine so the hash is the same for both the device and the emulator.

```
public class main extends Activity {

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiLifeCycleHelper;
    private boolean isResumed = false;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView userNameView;
    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.d("YOSI", "" + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());

        // Add code to print out the key hash
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.activity", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:",
                        Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPickerActivity(PickerActivity.FRIEND_PICKER, 1);

            }
        });

        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.selection_profile_pic);
        userNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection_user_name);
        profilePictureView.setCropped(true);

        uiLifeCycleHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, new StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                Log.v("log_tag", "Token=" + session.getAccessToken());
                Log.v("log_tag", "Token=" + session.isOpened());

                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Log.d("SESSION", "Is Opened");
                    onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
                }


                try {
                    Log.d("EXCEPTION", "" + exception.getMessage());
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        uiLifeCycleHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                                userNameView.setText(user.getFirstName());
                                String json = user.getInnerJSONObject()
                                        .toString();
                                Log.d("JSON", json);
                            }
                        }

                        if (response.getError() != null) {

                        }

                    }
                });

        request.executeAsync();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session,
            SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            makeMeRequest(session);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);

    }

    private void startPickerActivity(Uri data, int requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setData(data);
        intent.setClass(this, PickerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiLifeCycleHelper.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiLifeCycleHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiLifeCycleHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiLifeCycleHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try call `uiLifeCycleHelper.onActivityResult` in the `onActivityResult` method.